# Restrictions on the form of a function imposed by Lorentz invariance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity

I need help proving a couple of theorems regarding the most general form of a function with some particular Lorentz-transformation properties.
By the way, the question is possibly (though not necessarily) more suited for Math.SE, so if the moderators find it appropriate I invite them to migrate the question.

Any suggestion is welcome, thank you.

1. Suppose that the functions $C^\mu\colon \mathbb R ^3 \times \mathbb R ^3 \to \mathbb C$, $\mu =0,1,2,3$, satisfy:$$C^\mu (\widetilde \Lambda (\mathbf p) ,\widetilde \Lambda (\mathbf q))=\Lambda ^\mu _{\nu}C^\nu (\mathbf p, \mathbf q)$$for any proper, orthocronous, Lorentz boost. (The notation $\widetilde\Lambda (\mathbf p)$ refers to the spatial part of the four vector $\Lambda p$, with $p^0 = +\sqrt {m^2 +\mathbf p^2}$, the parameter $m$ is fixed).

   I want to prove that the most general form of $C^\mu$ is:$$C^\mu( \mathbf p,\mathbf q)=A(\mathbf p,\mathbf q)p^\mu +B(\mathbf p ,\mathbf q )q^\mu , $$
   with $A,B\colon \mathbb R ^3 \times \mathbb R ^3 \to \mathbb C$ satisfying $A(\widetilde \Lambda (\mathbf p) , \widetilde \Lambda (\mathbf q))=A(\mathbf p ,\mathbf q)$ and similarly for $B$.
2. Moreover, $A$ and $B$ depend only on $(p-q)^2=(p^0-q^0)^2-(\mathbf p -\mathbf q )^2$.

Both propositions are quite natural, however I honestly don't see how to rigorously prove them.  For the first one, the only non-trivial implication that I see is $$\text dC^\mu\circ \text d \widetilde \Lambda =\Lambda ^{\mu}_{\nu}\text dC^\nu,$$ for the differentials of $C^\mu$ (note that $\widetilde \Lambda$ is not a linear transformation), but I don't know if this can help. Moreover, I suspect that it should be easier to prove the theorems by considering the functions as defined on  $$M\times M\subset \mathbb R ^4 \times \mathbb R ^4$, where $M:=[{p^2}=m, p^0>0]$$.

Comment: Your claim is false: $A$ and $B$ can be functions of all scalars you can construct out of $p$ and $q$. $(p-q)_\mu (p-q)^\mu$ is not the only one. Another is $p_\mu q^\mu$ for instance...

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are functions of $p_\mu p^\mu$, $q_\mu q^\mu$ and $p_\mu q^\mu$ only.

Comment: @ValterMoretti, thank you for the observation. Here $p$ and $q$ are confined on the shell $p^2=m^2$. That means that $p^2=q^2=m^2$ are fixed and enter in $C^\mu$ only as parameters.

Comment: OK, it remains $p_\mu q^\mu$

Comment: However it is equivalent to write that $A$ and $B$ are functions of $(p-q)^2$ as you wrote...

Comment: Yes. Just to be sure, I mean that $A(\mathbf p ,\mathbf q)=a((p-q)^2)$ for some function $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your defining relation uses spatial components $\bf p$, $\bf q$ only, probably because $p$ and $q$ are on the mass shell, it is more convenient to rewrite it simply as
$$
C^\mu(\Lambda p, \Lambda q) = \Lambda^{\mu\;}_{\;\nu} C^\nu(p,q)
$$
In this form it is immediately reminiscent of a homogeneity relation in $\Lambda$, so let's treat it similarly. Consider an infinitesimal change $\Lambda \rightarrow \Lambda + \delta\Lambda$ and the variations thereof, leading to
$$
(\delta \Lambda)^{\rho\;}_{\;\sigma} p^\sigma \frac{\partial C^\mu}{\partial (\Lambda p)^\rho} (\Lambda p, \Lambda q)+ (\delta \Lambda)^{\rho\;}_{\;\sigma} q^\sigma \frac{\partial C^\mu}{\partial (\Lambda q)^\rho}(\Lambda p, \Lambda q) = (\delta \Lambda)^{\mu\;}_{\;\nu} C^\nu(p,q) 
$$
where $g_{\rho\alpha}(\delta\Lambda)^{\alpha\;}_{\;\sigma} + g_{\sigma\alpha} (\delta\Lambda)^{\alpha\;}_{\;\rho} = (\delta\Lambda)_{\rho\sigma} + (\delta\Lambda)_{\sigma\rho} = 0$. The derivatives on the left hand side further give
$$
\frac{\partial C^\mu}{\partial (\Lambda p)^\rho}(\Lambda p, \Lambda q) = \frac{\partial p_\alpha}{\partial (\Lambda p)^\rho} \frac{\partial}{\partial p^\alpha}C^\mu(\Lambda p, \Lambda q) = (\Lambda^{-1})^{\alpha\;}_{\;\rho} \frac{\partial }{\partial p^\alpha}\Lambda^{\mu\;}_{\;\nu} C^\nu(p, q) = \\
= \Lambda_{\rho\;}^{\;\alpha} \Lambda^{\mu\;}_{\;\nu} \frac{\partial C^\nu}{\partial p^\alpha}(p, q) \\
\frac{\partial C^\mu}{\partial (\Lambda q)^\rho}(\Lambda p, \Lambda q) = \Lambda_{\rho\;}^{\;\alpha} \Lambda^{\mu\;}_{\;\nu} \frac{\partial C^\nu}{\partial q^\alpha}(p, q)
$$
Substitute this in the original equation and rearrange as
$$
(\delta \Lambda)^{\rho\;}_{\;\sigma} \Lambda_{\rho\;}^{\;\alpha} \Lambda^{\mu\;}_{\;\nu} \left[p^\sigma \frac{\partial C^\nu}{\partial p^\alpha}(p, q) + q^\sigma \frac{\partial C^\nu}{\partial q^\alpha}(p, q) \right] = (\delta \Lambda)^{\mu\;}_{\;\nu} C^\nu(p,q)
$$
then contract both sides with $\Lambda_{\mu\;}^{\;\beta}$ and use $\Lambda_{\mu\;}^{\;\beta}\Lambda^{\mu\;}_{\;\nu} = g^{\beta\;}_{\;\nu} = \delta_{\beta\nu}$:
$$
(\delta \Lambda)^{\rho\;}_{\;\sigma} \Lambda_{\rho\;}^{\;\alpha} \left[p^\sigma \frac{\partial C^\beta}{\partial p^\alpha}(p, q) + q^\sigma \frac{\partial C^\beta}{\partial q^\alpha}(p, q) \right] = (\delta \Lambda)^{\mu\;}_{\;\nu} \Lambda_{\mu\;}^{\;\beta} C^\nu(p,q)
$$
With some relabeling this can be rearranged now as
$$
(\delta \Lambda)^{\rho\;}_{\;\sigma} \Lambda_{\rho\;}^{\;\alpha}\left[p^\sigma \frac{\partial C^\beta}{\partial p^\alpha}(p, q) + q^\sigma \frac{\partial C^\beta}{\partial q^\alpha}(p, q) - g^{\beta\;}_{\;\alpha} C^\sigma(p,q) \right] = 0 
$$
Since $\delta \Lambda$ and $\Lambda$ vary independently we are left with 
$$
g^{\beta\;}_{\;\alpha} C^\sigma(p,q) = p^\sigma \frac{\partial C^\beta}{\partial p^\alpha}(p, q) + q^\sigma \frac{\partial C^\beta}{\partial q^\alpha}(p, q)
$$
Contract again with $g^{\alpha\;}_{\;\beta}$, relabel, and obtain
$$
C^\mu(p,q) = \frac{1}{4}\left[p^\mu \frac{\partial C^\nu}{\partial p^\nu}(p, q) + q^\mu \frac{\partial C^\nu}{\partial q^\nu}(p, q)\right]
$$
where $\frac{\partial C^\nu}{\partial p^\nu} = g^{\nu\;}_{\;\alpha}\frac{\partial C^\alpha}{\partial p^\nu}$, $\frac{\partial C^\nu}{\partial q^\nu} = g^{\nu\;}_{\;\alpha}\frac{\partial C^\alpha}{\partial q^\nu}$. We can easily see that given the transformation law for the $C^\mu(p,q)$ the latter quantities are invariant: 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial (\Lambda p)^\nu} C^\nu(\Lambda p, \Lambda q) = (\Lambda^{-1})^{\alpha\;}_{\;\nu}\Lambda^{\nu\;}_{\;\beta}\frac{\partial C^\beta}{\partial p^\alpha}(p,q) = g^{\alpha\;}_{\;\beta} \frac{\partial C^\beta}{\partial p^\alpha}(p,q) \equiv \frac{\partial C^\nu}{\partial p^\nu}(p,q) , \;\;\;\text{etc.}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the elaborate proof. Just one comment: the whole proof works under the assumption that $C^\mu (p,q)$ is defined (and differentiable) on the whole spacetime, or equivalently that it depends smoothly on the mass $m$.

Comment: Welcome. As for the nature of the $C^\mu$-s, that is the safe assumption, yes.